# How do I write a dinamically growing table in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have to make a loan calculator excel and I want it to write out the results in a table. Now I did jsut wrote it to write the first line, because I don't know how should I refer the cells in an excel vba cycle. I would like it to just show the exact numbers of payments (the whole payment, the principal part of it and the interest part of it, it's an annuity type calculator) when I click on calculate instead I write the formula in every cell I maybe need to use. I would just like to those to be blank instead of writing the error message of #NUM! error where there is no payment required to be (for example it's a 6 months loan, and not 12 so it would write #NUM! error after the 6. monts). My code look like this ATM. 
hitelosszeg = present value, futamido = number of payments, kamatlab = interest rate, torlesztoresz = payment, kamatresz = interest part of payment, tokeresz = principal part of payment, hiteldij = whole interest.

```
Sub KALKULÁL() '
' KALKULÁL Makró'
If Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1 Then
Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1
End If

    Dim hitelosszeg As Double
    Dim futamido As Double
    Dim kamatlab As Double
    Dim periodus As Double
    Dim torlesztoresz As Double
    Dim tokeresz As Double
    Dim kamatresz As Double
    Dim vegosszeg As Double
    Dim hiteldij As Double


    hitelosszeg = Range("B9")
    futamido = Range("B10")
    kamatlab = Range("B11")


    If IsNull(hitelosszeg) Then
        MsgBox ("A hitelösszeg megadása kötelező!")
        If IsNull(futamido) Then
        MsgBox ("A futamidő megadása kötelező!")
        End If
        If IsNull(kamatlab) Then
        MsgBox ("A kamatláb megadása kötelező!")
        End If
    Else
        periodus = Range("A16").Value
        torlesztoresz = Pmt(kamatlab / 12, futamido, hitelosszeg) * -1
        tokeresz = PPmt(kamatlab / 12, periodus, futamido, hitelosszeg) * -1
        kamatresz = IPmt(kamatlab / 12, periodus, futamido, hitelosszeg) * -1
        Range("B16") = Round(torlesztoresz, 0)
        Range("C16") = Round(tokeresz, 0)
        Range("D16") = Round(kamatresz, 0)
        vegosszeg = torlesztoresz * futamido
        hiteldij = vegosszeg - hitelosszeg
        Range("C13") = Round(vegosszeg, 0)
        Range("F13") = Round(hiteldij, 0)



    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean you just want to hide errors? Use an IF  - if(error,"",result).

Comment: No, I would like that if the datas would be loeaded from the VBA code to a dinamically growing table with a cycle, but if there is no more data, leave those lines blank (the datas from 1 payment are in a line).

Comment: Sorry, at the start I tried referencing in r1c1 but it did not work well for me, so I went back to A1 reference, just look at it without this :)
If Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1 Then
Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1
End If

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the relevance of that line. If you are using a table it should expand as you add more rows.

Comment: Yeah it is working like that, but my real problem is that I don't know how to refer to and change the cell in a vba cycle like ,,for" or ,,Do While". How to make it jump from A16 to A17 after it calculated the datas in A16's row.

Comment: Have you done any research into VBA loops? There is plenty out there, including on this site.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're trying to "reinvent the wheel"?  There are a lot of very well done loan calculator templates out there that could save you a whole lot of work.

Comment: Yeah, but i didn't really find anything. Frank Ball, it's a university task and I don't want to make it obvious, anyway I work in a bank and by this I think I can learn so much so I chose to do this. :)